# Titanium TableView disappears when two TableViews are on same view

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

This is for a mobile app, running on the iPhone simulator, using SDK v 3.0.2 GA and the Alloy framework.

I have a window that has a tableview with an autocompleting search bar atop that table view. When the autocomplete begins to fire, it displays a tableview with the results below the search box, allowing a user to select from the results.

This all works fine, except that including the TableView on the search view causes the TableView on the original window to disappear.

The code is as follows:

**myPlaces.xml**

```
<Alloy>
  <Window id="myDrawersWin">
    <RightNavButton>
        <Button id="showMyDrawers" title="Show Drawers" />
    </RightNavButton>
    <Require src="findPlace" id="findPlace"/>
    <TableView id="placeListTable"/>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**findPlace.xml**

```
<Alloy>
  <View id="searchContainer">
    <TextField id="searchInput" hintText="Find a place..." />
  </View>
  <TableView id="searchResultsTable"/>
</Alloy>
```

**findPlace.js**

```
$.searchInput.addEventListener("change", function(){
   if ($.searchInput.value.length > 2 && $.searchInput.value != "Find a place...") {

    // do the search and get a response successfully

            _.each(returnedVenues, function(venue){
                tblData.push(Alloy.createController("venueSearchListItem", venue).getView());
            });

            $.searchResultsTable.setData(tblData);

            $.searchResultsTable.visible = true;

        },
        onerror: function(e){
            console.log("error");
            console.log(e);
        }
    });

    // invoke the HTTP client here

  }
  else {
        $.searchResultsTable.visible = false;
  }
});
```

**findPlace.xml**

```
"#searchContainer":{
    width: "100%",
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#B8D0DB",
    top: 0
}


"#searchInput":{
    width: "80%",
    height: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
}

"#searchResultsTable":{
    width: "80%",
    visible: false
}
```

If I take out the TableView in `findPlace.xml`, the original TableView on the window (placeListTable) shows up fine. If I add it back, it disappears. Also, if I move the TableView inside of `<View id="searchContainer">` it *will* show up (but obviously, doesn't fit, due to the height restriction on `searchContainer`).

Any ideas? Is this a bug, or am I doing something stupid here?

Thanks for any help.

Justin

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to this problem, and as I suspected, it was stupidity.

The problem was that I'd set `layout:vertical` on the window stylesheet, meaning that the second TableView was displaying below the other one. Removing that solved the problem.